# Weak convergence equivalent to convergence of distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I'm trying to understand the following proof:

[image]

I don't see where the Lipschitz property of the $f$ is needed. Why isn't bounded and continuous enough?

Can somebody explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: Which $f_n$ are you talking about? Do you mean $f$?

Comment: @saz: sorry, yes, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lipschitz-contuity of $f$ implies

$$\begin{align*} \int_x^y f(t) \, d\mu_n(t)  &= \int_x^y [(f(t)-f(x))+f(x)] \, d\mu_n(t) \\ &\leq (f(x)+ \sup\{|f(t)-f(x)|; t \in [x,y]\}) \cdot (F_n(y)-F_n(x)) \\ &\leq (f(x)+\epsilon) (F_n(y)-F_n(x)) \end{align*}$$

for any two points $x<y$ such that $|x-y|<\epsilon$. This estimate is e.g. needed in order to estimate $\int f \, d\mu_n$ from above by

$$(F_n(y_0)+F_n(\infty)-F_n(y_N)) + \sum_{i=1}^N (f(y_i)+\epsilon)(F_n(y_i)-F_n(y_{i-1})).$$